# python function for list of lists n long, with each element 0-m

Tags: python, recursion

I need to make a function so that I can put in two parameters, an order, and a max, and return a list of all of the lists 'order' long and with each element ranging from 0 to 'max'. I suspect I may need to use recursion, but I am getting lost in this.

so order = 2 max = 3 should return

```
[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,0], [1,1], ... ,[3,3]]
```

and order=4, max=5 should return

```
[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,2], ...  [3,3,3,3]]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide us with what you have done so far and where exactly are you facing a problem?

Comment: If you *must* program this yourself, search on line for "all combinations of a set" + iteration + recursion; there are a lot of code examples already available.

Comment: Actually if I still have you, I noticed your answer is almost what I need, but it seems that it fails on a couple of cases I want, a copy/paste gives me ... (0,2), (0,3), (1,1) ... (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)... I'm not quite sure I understand what's going on here

Answer (score 2):

Note that in general, @Prune's answer is the weapon of choice, here.

As for recursion: The requested list can be constructed recursively as

1. The list of length `1` is the list of all `1`-element lists with elements from the initial set:

`[1] -> [[1]]`

`[1, 2] -> [[1], [2]]`

`[1, 2, 3] -> [[1], [2], [3]]`

In Python:

`l1 = [[item] for item in range(0, max + 1)]`

2. The list `ln1` of length `n + 1` consists of the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of  `ln` of length `n`  with `l1` with the elements joined by list concatenation.

In Python:

`ln1 = [a + b for a in combine(base, n - 1) for b in combine(base, 1)]`

```
def combinations(base, n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return [[item] for item in base]
    else:
        return [a + b for a in combine(base, n - 1) for b in combine(base, 1)]
```

`itertools.combinations_with_replacements()` is both faster and more memory efficient. It's also an existing wheel rather than a new one.

Comment: Great notes. This is very interesting!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I (probably wisely) chickened out on the recursive implementation of the cross-product between two lists. In Python, the above is stupidly slow enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion; all you need is the Python [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) package:

```
import itertools
num_list = [x for x in range(max+1)]

for one_combo in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(num_list, order):
    ...
```

Of course, you can combine the two computational lines; it's just easier to see this way.

Comment: I think he was asking for it using recursion though. Clearly you can do this with libraries.

Comment: It's not "clearly" unless you're that familiar with Python libraries.  I see no indication either way of OP's background.

Comment: Yeah, but his question was tagged with recursion, so I'm assuming he wants recursion.

Comment: The posting says "may need".

Comment: No need for recursion, just suspected it might since I'm not familiar with itertools. I'll have to read up on it. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, trying this in an IDLE shell, why can I only loop through output once? if I try to print for _ in output more than once it gives me nothing?

Comment: @ChadBockholt Because you are getting a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). The generator is consumed when you are iterating over it. just do `list(output)` before anything else.

Comment: Actually if I still have you, I noticed your answer is almost what I need, but it seems that it fails on a couple of cases I want, a copy/paste gives me        ... (0,2), (0,3), (1,1) ... (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)... I'm not quite sure I understand what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that uses recursion to solve the problem. When you are dealing with recursion, make sure you have a base case and a general case.

```
def recurseNumbers(order, mx):
    if order == 1:
        return [[n] for n in range(mx + 1)]
    else:
        total_array = []
        for num in range(mx + 1):
            numbers = recurseNumbers(order - 1, mx)
            for number in numbers:
                total_array.append([num] + number)
        return total_array
```

Also note that Python list addition makes this relatively simple. `["a"] + ["b"] = ["a", "b"]`

Comment: Nitpicking: `range(mx)` doesn't include `mx` as requested.